# ResourceStore In ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

HI all,

I'm modifying j2me application into mobile web application. In J2me, there is one concept called persistent store. Is there any thing like that in ASP.net.
If so, please let me know...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right this persistent store is on the actual mobile device. If this is the case then there is nothing like this in ASP.NET. I think local storage using cookies is unreliable on mobile devices so you would need to store data server side.

Comment: Yep, J2ME is an environment for building apps that you install on a mobile device, not web sites. I would almost suggest SilverLight, but they still haven't even got that on Windows Mobile...